# how change the properties of div on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://razorpay.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=brand&gclid=CjwKCAjwqarbBRBtEiwArlfEIN_Jl5kiLQRB-zp23dItXm7JMpGNXDK5opevk4W-iEgBRhOjsIZKoBoCSokQAvD_BwE

in this website(under section-do more with razorpay) how they are changing the properties of div on hover and displaying picture 
can anyone help me understand by showing sample code.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS

Here's an example:

```
div {
    display: none;
}

span:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp